# d3.js function called when event occured cannot keep changes permanently after return

Tags: d3.js, websocket, bottle

I have server and client that exchange data through websocket(bottle weboscket). So when start button is pressed server starts sending data to the client and client updates graph being plotted by d3.js by sliding it to the left. When stop button is presed client send stop message to the server and server closes the websocket connection. and client side triggers this function when websocket is closed

```
ws.onclose = function(evt) {
    plotFinalGraph(w,s);
    alert("closing...");
}
```

I especially put this alert function to see if it is really calling plotFinalGraph(). This final graph is plotted for very short while and disappears when alert pop screen is closed. I thought like this is not proper using of d3.js library or websocket together that is why I did not posted codes here. What should I do to keep changes made by plotFinalGraph() function even when onclose() function is returned?

Comment: We can't tell you anything without seeing the code.

Comment: Hello Lars since codes are too long I just skipped the codes. Thank you for your understanding. Yesterday I tried some method and it worked for me and forgot to update it here. I will now update my question.